# Simple Mobile friendly way for jQuery to let 3 sliders share between a single distributable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to implement in jQuery a UI where 3 sliders that represents 3 different attributes to share a common max amount of distributable skill points.

e.g.

```
 Distributable Skill Points = 100

 strength      0------------------[]--------------- 100   (45)
 agility       0------[]--------------------------- 100   (10)
 intelligence  0------------[]--------------------- 100   (20)

                                          remaining pts   (15)
```

The user should not be able to add more points if they try to distribute more points beyond the shared limit (Distributable Skill Points)

I have tried doing this in AngularJS ([my JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twothumbsticks/dja9oqn7/)) but the suggested solutions were too complicated for me (services, directives, ng-change, $watch) 
I hope there is a simpler way to achieve this in Jquery or javascript.

Comment: [Asking a good question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As a rule of thumb, it is recommended you attempt the problem first and *then present your code*, which we will attempt to improve in order to solve your issue. Asking the people on this website to implement you an entire solution from scratch is generally viewed as bad practice

Comment: Hi Sir thank you for reason of downvote.  I have a fiddle in my question showing how I did it in AngularJS and used a Directive.  I am not asking for an answer that is equivalent to a complete solution but just what to use and why it is better.  I spent the whole day using a directive that turned out is not even mobile friendly when I got it working.  If I try and fiddle again without asking for which approach to use (pure javascript or jquery mobile or just jquyer) I was afraid to waste that much time again.

Comment: I apologise, I did not realise you linked to your fiddle! In the future, best to label your fiddle as just "fiddle", rather than AngularJS. And if it's any consolation, I didn't downvote you. I would recommend looking into using [JqueryUI sliders](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) If you want a more compatible solution.

Comment: Apology accepted sir.  I am also sorry I should have used a better Link name like fiddle to not cause misunderstanding and confusion will update it now sir.